# An error has occurred in the script on this page no such interface supported

Tags: javascript, .net, webforms

I am currently loading an PDF in the webpage and displaying it to user. It does not throw any error when i run it from IDE but when deployed it gives this wierd error and users click continue it works fine. Any suggestions on how to fix this. I dont want to change IE settings as we have multiple clients it will be tough to convey them all.

:https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWqRO.png

Answer (score 0):

If you're just spitting out a .pdf file, try opening the .pdf in a text editor and checking character 17 on line 15.  It may just be a unicode character.

Depending on how the pdf is created, you may be able to replace that character with a similar UTF equivalent, encode it, etc.